# How do I send ETH from an account to another in Hardhat?

Tags: transactions, ether, javascript, hardhat, sendtransaction

I am trying those methods (both) and neither worked for me:

```
signer.sendTransaction({ to, value });
```

(and)

```
provider.send("eth_sendTransaction", [{ from, to, value }]);
```

> Would be great if your answer could also include an account impersonation example, as that's exactly why I need to send `ETH`.

Impersonated accounts would most likely have **0 ETH**, and so would need to have some `ETH` sent over before being used to initiate any TX.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I am getting the accounts

```
    const [owner,  feeCollector, operator] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

```
    await owner.sendTransaction({
      to: operator.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"), // Sends exactly 1.0 ether
    });
```